# Why is my instance variable not in __dict__?

Tags: python

If I create a class `A` as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'A'
```

Inspecting the `__dict__` member looks like `{'name': 'A'}`

If however I create a class `B`:

```
class B:
    name = 'B'
```

`__dict__` is empty.

What is the difference between the two, and why doesn't `name` show up in `B`'s `__dict__`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`B.name` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.  It shows up in `B.__dict__`, but not in `b = B(); b.__dict__`.

The distinction is obscured somewhat because when you access an attribute on an instance, the class dict is a fallback.  So in the above example, `b.name` will give you the value of `B.name`.

Answer (score 13):

```
class A:
    def _ _init_ _(self):
        self.name = 'A'
a = A()
```

Creates an attribute on the object instance a of type A and it can therefore be found in: `a.__dict__`

```
class B:
    name = 'B'
b = B()
```

Creates an attribute on the class B and the attribute can be found in `B.__dict__` alternatively if you have an instance b of type B you can see the class level attributes in `b.__class__.__dict__`