# Getting attributes of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes

I want to get the attributes of a class, say:

```
class MyClass():
  a = "12"
  b = "34"

  def myfunc(self):
    return self.a
```

using `MyClass.__dict__` gives me a list of attributes and functions, and even functions like `__module__` and `__doc__`. While `MyClass().__dict__` gives me an empty dict unless I explicitly set an attribute value of that instance.

I just want the attributes, in the example above those would be: `a` and `b`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inspect python class attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241171/inspect-python-class-attributes)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Try the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) module. `getmembers` and the various tests should be helpful.

EDIT:

For example,

```
class MyClass(object):
    a = '12'
    b = '34'
    def myfunc(self):
        return self.a

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(MyClass, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
[('__class__', type),
 ('__dict__',
  <dictproxy {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
   '__doc__': None,
   '__module__': '__main__',
   '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
   'a': '34',
   'b': '12',
   'myfunc': <function __main__.myfunc>}>),
 ('__doc__', None),
 ('__module__', '__main__'),
 ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>),
 ('a', '34'),
 ('b', '12')]
```

Now, the special methods and attributes get on my nerves- those can be dealt with in a number of ways, the easiest of which is just to filter based on name.

```
>>> attributes = inspect.getmembers(MyClass, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
>>> [a for a in attributes if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))]
[('a', '34'), ('b', '12')]
```

...and the more complicated of which can include special attribute name checks or even metaclasses ;)

Comment: yup this is great! I used this: 
`attributes = inspect.getmembers(MyClass, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))`
`print [a[0] for a in attributes if '_' not in a[0]]`

Comment: Be careful- that won't include attributes `like_this`! It'll also avoid "private" attributes, which you might've done on purpose.

Comment: Hi, I loved that too with a slight clarification : in the expression `inspect.getmembers(MyClass, ...`, `MyClass` can be replaced by a class or  an object, and if you need the list of the values of your objects, you must replace `MyClass` by your object variable (or `self` if you put this expression in a `def __repr__()` method like me).

Comment: I used this (in Python3) to get a function that looked for the '__dict__'  value:
`i = inspect.getmembers(MyClass, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a))); z = [_[1] for _ in i if _[0] in '__dict__'][0]` and then it's just a matter of getting the keys from z.

Comment: Is it possible to get the `attributes` in the same order that they were stated inside the `class`? This code is returning me the `attributes` in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 84):

```
def props(cls):   
  return [i for i in cls.__dict__.keys() if i[:1] != '_']

properties = props(MyClass)
```

Comment: This will include method names

Comment: Woudn't be more clear to check: `if not i.startswith('_')` instead of `if i[:1] != '_'`?

Comment: Note: if we talk about child class (inherited), then `.__dict__.keys()` will not include attributes from parent.

Answer (score 52):

Getting only the **instance attributes** is easy.
But getting also the **class attributes** without the functions is a bit more tricky.

## Instance attributes only

If you only have to list **instance attributes** just use
**`for attribute, value in my_instance`.[`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).`items()`**

```py
>>> from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.a = 2
...     self.b = 3
...   def print_instance_attributes(self):
...     for attribute, value in self.__dict__.items():
...       print(attribute, '=', value)
...
>>> my_instance = MyClass()
>>> my_instance.print_instance_attributes()
a = 2
b = 3
>>> for attribute, value in my_instance.__dict__.items():
...   print(attribute, '=', value)
...
a = 2
b = 3
```

## Instance and class attributes

To get also the **class attributes** without the functions, the trick is to use [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#callable).

**But [static methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod) are [not always `callable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45375944/938111)!**

Therefore, instead of using `callable(value)` use
**`callable`([`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#getattr)(`MyClass, attribute))`**

### Example

```py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)

class MyClass(object):
   a = "12"
   b = "34"               # class attributes

   def __init__(self, c, d):
     self.c = c
     self.d = d           # instance attributes

   @staticmethod
   def mystatic():        # static method
       return MyClass.b

   def myfunc(self):      # non-static method
     return self.a

   def print_instance_attributes(self):
     print('[instance attributes]')
     for attribute, value in self.__dict__.items():
        print(attribute, '=', value)

   def print_class_attributes(self):
     print('[class attributes]')
     for attribute in MyClass.__dict__.keys():
       if attribute[:2] != '__':
         value = getattr(MyClass, attribute)
         if not callable(value):
           print(attribute, '=', value)

v = MyClass(4,2)
v.print_class_attributes()
v.print_instance_attributes()
```

**Note:** `print_class_attributes()` should be [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod)
      but not in this *stupid and simple* example.

### Result for [python2](/questions/tagged/python2)

```py
$ python2 ./print_attributes.py
[class attributes]
a = 12
b = 34
[instance attributes]
c = 4
d = 2
```

### Same result for [python3](/questions/tagged/python3)

```py
$ python3 ./print_attributes.py
[class attributes]
b = 34
a = 12
[instance attributes]
c = 4
d = 2
```

Comment: In Python3.8, the code gives the result of `class attributes` same as `instance attributes`.

Comment: Great answer. For those wondering about `__dict__` vs `vars()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21297203

Comment: There was an edit that broke this example for more than a year. The `print_class_attributes` function has to reference `MyClass` directly, unless you use the alternative of making it a `@classmethod` in which case it could use `self`/`cls` instead.

Answer (score 36):

`myfunc` **is** an attribute of `MyClass`. That's how it's found when you run:

```
myinstance = MyClass()
myinstance.myfunc()
```

It looks for an attribute on `myinstance` named `myfunc`, doesn't find one, sees that `myinstance` is an instance of `MyClass` and looks it up there.

So the *complete* list of attributes for `MyClass` is:

```
>>> dir(MyClass)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'b', 'myfunc']
```

(Note that I'm using dir just as a quick and easy way to list the members of the class: it should only be used in an exploratory fashion,  not in production code)

If you only want particular attributes, you'll need to filter this list using some criteria, because `__doc__`, `__module__`, and `myfunc` aren't special in any way, they're attributes in exactly the same way that `a` and `b` are.

I've never used the inspect module referred to by Matt and Borealid, but from a brief link it looks like it has tests to help you do this, but you'll need to write your own predicate function, since it seems what you want is roughly the attributes that *don't* pass the `isroutine` test and don't start and end with two underscores.

Also note: by using `class MyClass():` in Python 2.7 you're using the wildly out of date old-style classes. Unless you're doing so deliberately for compatibility with extremely old libraries, you should be instead defining your class as `class MyClass(object):`. In Python 3 there are no "old-style" classes, and this behaviour is the default. However, using newstyle classes will get you a *lot* more automatically defined attributes:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
        a = "12"
        b = "34"
        def myfunc(self):
            return self.a
>>> dir(MyClass)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b', 'myfunc']
```

Comment: One cannot depend on `dir()`: "_Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, **it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names**, and **its detailed behavior may change across releases**._" (see [documentation of `dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir)).

Comment: @Tadeck: Good point. I was using it illustratively rather than suggesting it as a solution, since it wouldn't easily allow you to filter the attributes based on what they refer to. But I should be more explicit about that.

Answer (score 12):

`MyClass().__class__.__dict__`

However, the "right" was to do this is via the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Comment: `MyClass().__class__.__dict__` == `MyClass.__dict__`

Comment: @yak's comment isn't quite true. See the following about the differences between class and instance attributes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805/why-is-my-instance-variable-not-in-dict.

Comment: @sholsapp actually @yak is right. The link you provided says that `MyClass().__class__.__dict__ != MyClass().__dict__`, but yak is not including the parentheses on the right-hand side, in the case of which s/he is correct

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

class MyClass:
    a = "12"
    b = "34"

    def myfunc(self):
        return self.a

attributes = [a for a, v in MyClass.__dict__.items()
              if not re.match('<function.*?>', str(v))
              and not (a.startswith('__') and a.endswith('__'))]
```

For an instance of MyClass, such as

```
mc = MyClass()
```

use `type(mc)` in place of `MyClass` in the list comprehension.  However, if one dynamically adds an attribute to `mc`, such as `mc.c = "42"`, the attribute won't show up when using `type(mc)` in this strategy.  It only gives the attributes of the original class.

To get the complete dictionary for a class instance, you would need to COMBINE the dictionaries of `type(mc).__dict__` and `mc.__dict__`.

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.c = "42"

# Python 3.5
combined_dict = {**type(mc).__dict__, **mc.__dict__}

# Or Python < 3.5
def dict_union(d1, d2):
    z = d1.copy()
    z.update(d2)
    return z

combined_dict = dict_union(type(mc).__dict__, mc.__dict__)

attributes = [a for a, v in combined_dict.items()
              if not re.match('<function.*?>', str(v))
              and not (a.startswith('__') and a.endswith('__'))]
```

Comment: Really neat solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "get" an attribute, there is a **very simple answer**, which should be obvious: getattr

```
class MyClass(object):
a = '12'
b = '34'
def myfunc(self):
    return self.a

>>> getattr(MyClass, 'a')
'12'

>>> getattr(MyClass, 'myfunc')
<function MyClass.myfunc at 0x10de45378>
```

It works dandy both in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

If you want a list of these items, you will still need to use inspect.

Comment: Is that answer too simple and too correct to deserve any points, and should even deserve bad points? It seems that economy and simplicity no longer pay off nowadays.

Comment: He wants to _list_ attributes, not to _get_. See an example at the lower part of the question.

Comment: @ogurets It is clearly stated in his question that he wants to _get_ attributes, not to _list_ them (as for _listing_ see, the lower part of my answer).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2 & 3, whitout imports, filtering objects by their address

### Solutions in short:

Return ***dict {attribute_name: attribute_value}***, objects filtered. i.e `{'a': 1, 'b': (2, 2), 'c': [3, 3]}`

```
{k: val for k, val in self.__dict__.items() if not str(hex(id(val))) in str(val)}
```

Return ***list [attribute_names]***, objects filtered. i.e `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

```
[k for k, val in self.__dict__.items() if not str(hex(id(val))) in str(val)]
```

Return ***list [attribute_values]***, objects filtered. i.e `[1, (2, 2), [3, 3], {4: 4}]`

```
[val for k, val in self.__dict__.items() if not str(hex(id(val))) in str(val)]
```

---

### Not filtering objects

Removing the `if` condition. Return `{'a': 1, 'c': [3, 3], 'b': (2, 2), 'e': <function <lambda> at 0x7fc8a870fd70>, 'd': {4: 4}, 'f': <object object at 0x7fc8abe130e0>}`

```
{k: val for k, val in self.__dict__.items()}
```

---

### Solution in long

**As long as the default implementation of `__repr__` is not overridden** the `if` statement will return `True` if the hexadecimal representation of the location in memory of `val` is in the `__repr__` return string.

Regarding the default implementation of `__repr__` you could find useful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132458/8411453). In short:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<{0}.{1} object at {2}>'.format(
      self.__module__, type(self).__name__, hex(id(self)))
```

Wich returns a string like:

```
<__main__.Bar object at 0x7f3373be5998>
```

The location in memory of each element is got via the `id()` method.

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) says about id():

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
>   memory.

---

### Try by yourself

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self):

        self.a = 1
        self.b = (2, 2)
        self.c = [3, 3]
        self.d = {4: 4}
        self.e = lambda: "5"
        self.f = object()

    #__str__ or __repr__ as you prefer
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(

            # Solution in Short Number 1
            {k: val for k, val in self.__dict__.items() if not str(hex(id(val))) in str(val)}

        )

# Main
print(Bar())
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': [3, 3], 'b': (2, 2), 'd': {4: 4}}
```

---

**Note**:

- Tested with Python `2.7.13` and Python `3.5.3`
- In Python 2.x `.iteritems()` is preferred over `.items()`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if something similar has been made by now or not, but I made a nice attribute search function using vars(). vars() creates a dictionary of the attributes of a class you pass through it.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Bob'
        self.age = 36
        self.gender = 'Male'

s = vars(Player())
#From this point if you want to print all the attributes, just do print(s)

#If the class has a lot of attributes and you want to be able to pick 1 to see
#run this function
def play():
    ask = input("What Attribute?>: ")
    for key, value in s.items():
        if key == ask:
            print("self.{} = {}".format(key, value))
            break
    else:
        print("Couldn't find an attribute for self.{}".format(ask))
```

I'm developing a pretty massive Text Adventure in Python, my Player class so far has over 100 attributes. I use this to search for specific attributes I need to see.

Comment: unfortunately vars() won't return class attributes

Comment: Have you tried running the code I've posted? Vars can definitely return class attributes. Show me an example of how it doesn't? Maybe my code is incorrect. But assigning vars() to a variable and using a key,value search through that variable can return class attributes.

Comment: class T:x=1;
t = T(); 
vars(t)

Comment: You'll have to wait till I get off work to properly show you. But your code is incorrect. Your class object needs to define __init__(self) and x needs to be self.x=1. Then assign t = T() and use print(vars(t)) and it will show you a dictionary of all the class attributes.

Comment: no, those are instance attributes not class attributes, many sub-classes never call __init__. As I said, vars() won't return class attributes, you need to use dir() or inspect.getmembers()

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now, I was misunderstanding what you meant by class attributes, my bad. But I really don't see any clarity in dir() or inspect.getmembers(). Using vars() for class instances shows actual self attributes which is readable compared to the other methods. With dir() all I see is a bunch of nonsense for a class with 1 attribute. What I like seeing is that 1 actual attribute. Sorry for the misunderstanding though.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without inspect, I guess.

Take the following class:

```
 class Test:
   a = 1
   b = 2

   def __init__(self):
     self.c = 42

   @staticmethod
   def toto():
     return "toto"

   def test(self):
     return "test"
```

Looking at the members along with their types:

```
t = Test()
l = [ (x, eval('type(x.%s).__name__' % x)) for x in dir(a) ]
```

... gives:

```
[('__doc__', 'NoneType'),
 ('__init__', 'instancemethod'),
 ('__module__', 'str'),
 ('a', 'int'),
 ('b', 'int'),
 ('c', 'int'),
 ('test', 'instancemethod'),
 ('toto', 'function')]
```

So to output only the variables, you just have to filter the results by type, and names not starting with '__'. E.g.

```
filter(lambda x: x[1] not in ['instancemethod', 'function'] and not x[0].startswith('__'), l)

[('a', 'int'), ('b', 'int'), ('c', 'int')] # actual result
```

That's it.

*Note:* if you're using Python 3, convert the iterators to lists.

If you want a more robust way to do it, use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Answer (score 1):

My solution to get all attributes (not methods) of a class (if the class has a properly written docstring that has the attributes clearly spelled out):

```
def get_class_attrs(cls):
    return re.findall(r'\w+(?=[,\)])', cls.__dict__['__doc__'])
```

This piece `cls.__dict__['__doc__']` extracts the docstring of the class.

Comment: Important note: This will not work in some cases. It only works for classes with properly written docstrings that has the attributes clearly spelled out.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to figure out something similar to this question, so I wanted to post some background info that might be helpful to others facing the same in future.

Here's how it works in Python (from https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

`MyClass` is a class object, `MyClass()` is an instance of the class object. An instance's `__dict__` only hold attributes and methods specific to that instance (e.g. `self.somethings`). If an attribute or method is part of a class, it is in the class's `__dict__`. When you do `MyClass().__dict__`, an instance of `MyClass` is created with no attributes or methods besides the class attributes, thus the empty `__dict__`

So if you say `print(MyClass().b)`, Python first checks the new instance's dict `MyClass().__dict__['b']` and fails to find `b`. It then checks the class `MyClass.__dict__['b']` and finds `b`.

That's why you need the `inspect` module, to emulate that same search process.

Comment: Scott - A comment posted as an answer must get deleted, otherwise we'd be drowning in them. However, a partial answer or "helpful nudge" towards a solution is _still an answer_. You'll see how I reworded your post; hopefully I retained your intent. If not, you can further [edit] it into shape. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dir()` in a *list comprehension* to get the attribute names:

```
names = [p for p in dir(myobj) if not p.startswith('_')]
```

Use `getattr()` to get the attributes themselves:

```
attrs = [getattr(myobj, p) for p in dir(myobj) if not p.startswith('_')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to list the attributes? Seems that semantically your class is a collection. In this cases I recommend to use enum:

```
import enum

class myClass(enum.Enum):
     a = "12"
     b = "34"
```

List your attributes? Nothing easier than this:

```
for attr in myClass:
    print("Name / Value:", attr.name, attr.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

two function:

```
def get_class_attr(Cls) -> []:
    import re
    return [a for a, v in Cls.__dict__.items()
              if not re.match('<function.*?>', str(v))
              and not (a.startswith('__') and a.endswith('__'))]

def get_class_attr_val(cls):
    attr = get_class_attr(type(cls))
    attr_dict = {}
    for a in attr:
        attr_dict[a] = getattr(cls, a)
    return attr_dict
```

use:

```
>>> class MyClass:
    a = "12"
    b = "34"
    def myfunc(self):
        return self.a

>>> m = MyClass()
>>> get_class_attr_val(m)
{'a': '12', 'b': '34'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I want.

## Test Data

```py
class Base:
    b = 'b'


class MyClass(Base):
    a = '12'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        ...

    @property
    def p(self):
        return self.a

    def my_fun(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
print([name for name, val in inspect.getmembers(MyClass) if not name.startswith('_') and not callable(val)])  # need `import inspect`
print([_ for _ in dir(MyClass) if not _.startswith('_') and not callable(getattr(MyClass, _))])
# both are equ: ['a', 'b', 'p']

my_instance = MyClass('c')
print([_ for _ in dir(my_instance) if not _.startswith('_') and not callable(getattr(my_instance, _))])
# ['a', 'b', 'name', 'p']
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick function to get attribute that aren't magic properties and its value.

The usage of this utility recipe is just to get a quick introspection of a Class or Object without going deep in code or Documentations.
When I used it I just wanted to know that stuff that class has and devide what is a function and what is not, obviously I don't remember why thought I needed.

For the example, I used **[Python Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/)** but anything can be used really.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

def get_class_props(cls):
    for p in dir(cls):
        if not p.startswith('__'):
            attr_value = getattr(cls, p)
            if p.startswith('_'):
                 print(f'- {p} (private): {attr_value}')
            else:
                print(f'- {p}: {attr_value}')

get_class_props(fake)

- _factories (private): [<faker.generator.Generator object at 0x00000138D01D28C8>]
# - _factory_map (private): OrderedDict([('en_US', <faker.generator.Generator object at 0x00000138D01D28C8>)])
# - _locales (private): ['en_US']
# - _map_provider_method (private): <bound method Faker._map_provider_method of <faker.proxy.Faker object at 0x00000138D017AD88>>
# - _select_factory (private): <bound method Faker._select_factory of <faker.proxy.Faker object at 0x00000138D017AD88>>
# - _unique_proxy (private): <faker.proxy.UniqueProxy object at 0x00000138D017A308>
# - _weights (private): None
# - aba: <bound method Provider.aba of <faker.providers.bank.en_GB.Provider object at 0x00000138D281DBC8>>
# - add_provider: <bound method Generator.add_provider of <faker.generator.Generator object at 0x00000138D01D28C8>>
# - address: <bound method Provider.address of <faker.providers.address.en_US.Provider object at 0x00000138D2810DC8>>
# ...
```

---

To clean up the funcitions definitions,use this variations instead, wich defines 'function' whatever is a callable

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

def get_class_props(cls):
    for p in dir(cls):

        if not p.startswith('__'):
            attr_value = getattr(cls, p)
            is_function = callable(attr_value)

            if p.startswith('_'):
                 print(f'- {p} (private): {attr_value if not is_function else "funciton"}')
            else:
                print(f'- {p}: {attr_value if not is_function else "funciton"}')


- _factories (private): [<faker.generator.Generator object at 0x0000018A11D49C48>]
- _factory_map (private): OrderedDict([('en_US', <faker.generator.Generator object at 0x0000018A11D49C48>)])
- _locales (private): ['en_US']
- _map_provider_method (private): funciton
- _select_factory (private): funciton
- _unique_proxy (private): <faker.proxy.UniqueProxy object at 0x0000018A11D49748>
- _weights (private): None
- aba: funciton
get_class_props(fake)
```

Comment: This is a good answer! But it would be even more helpful if a real class was used (why not the OP's example?). It's not obvious what Faker does, or what attributes actually come from the generated class.

Comment: @MEMark This example is just a quick dirty utility recipe to get the attribute of a Class or Object, that's it really. When I used it is because I was probably looking what stuff the [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) had instead of going deep in documentation or code. Indeed, by the time I did not know how to implement Faker objs, that's why It can be used anywhere. I would say is just for a quick introspection. By the way I added some more clarity to the answer

Answer (score 0):

To add filtering features to the answers above :

```
import inspect
import re

def getClassMembers(obj, name=None, mbrcat='all'):
    # name : filter by attribute name
    # mbrcat : filter members by items category : all, methods or attributes
    dic_cat= { 
        'all' : lambda a: a, 
        'meth' : lambda a: inspect.isroutine(a), 
        'attr' : lambda a:  not(inspect.isroutine(a)) 
      } 
    return [str(_name)+'  :  '+str(member)  
            for _name, member in inspect.getmembers(obj, dic_cat[mbrcat])  
            if ((name==None) or (name in _name)) and (not(re.search(r'(^\_\_|\_\_$)' ,_name))) ]
```

Call #1:

```
getClassMembers(myClass.browse(264917),'state')

#Output:
['_compute_activity_state  :  <bound method xxx._compute_activity_state of classXXX >'
 'extract_state  :  no_extract_requested',
 'invoice_payment_state  :  paid',
 'state  :  posted'
]
```

Call #2:

```
getClassMembers(myClass.browse(264917),'state','meth')

#Output:
['_compute_activity_state  :  <bound method xxx._compute_activity_state of classXXX >'
]
```

Call #3:

```
getClassMembers(myClass.browse(264917),'state','attr')
#Ouput:
[
 'extract_state  :  no_extract_requested',
 'invoice_payment_state  :  paid',
 'state  :  posted'
]
```

Answer (score -1):

### The Problem

##### Prior answers have poor responsibility design

I don't feel any of the answers were able to address a basic scenario of a class dealing with `instance` and `class` attributes... WITHOUT needing to update the class to perform its own self-reporting.
This seems like a short-coming of most answers. Python can do better, albeit a little hacky.

#### Class Attributes

I started from an answer by [matt-luongo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058322/4901647). It was great for getting class attributes.

```
class A():
  self.a = 0
```

#### Instance Attributes

However... none of the answers met my four-item criteria to get the instance attributes.

```
class B():
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 0
```

In order to inspect the instance attributes, other answers required changes to the class itself that would force reporting of its internal contents. This approach defeats the intent of the python inspect module and the intent of general object, frame, function, class inspection.

### The Solution

#### Requirements

My solution needed to meet these standards:

- move all class inspection into an external function/package
- not require the class to self-report its own members
- not require the developer to write a new function, or update an existing one
- do not force a class to be instantiated *before* inspecting it
- (BONUS): This works for Py2 & Py3

#### The Process

You'll notice that part of this function uses [matt-luongo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058322/4901647) answer.
But for `class` member collection, I used the [inspect.getsource](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) function like this

```
code = inspect.getsource(B.__init__)
```

This returns a string of the `B.__init__(self)` function. Unfortunately, this code then has to be string parsed with regex. It's not clean but it works and meets all the above bullet points.

#### The Code

```
def get_class_members(class_obj=None):
    def is_init_var(test_in=''):
        var_searches = r'self.\w+[ =]+\w*'
        matches = re.findall(var_searches, test_in)
        if matches:
            return re.split(r'\W+', matches[0])[1]
        else:
            return None

    OUT = []
    members = inspect.getmembers(class_obj, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
    items = [x for x in members if not (x[0].startswith('__') and x[0].endswith('__'))]
    for item in items:
        OUT.append(item[0])
    init_code_lines = inspect.getsource(class_obj.__init__).split('\n')

    for line in init_code_lines:
        tmp = is_init_var(line)
        if tmp:
            OUT.append(tmp)
```

##### Example

In the case of Class C, this will return `['c', 'cc']`

```
class C():
    c = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.cc = 1

members = get_class_members(C)
print(members)
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this was three years ago, but for those who are to come by this question in the future, for me:

```
class_name.attribute
```

works just fine.

Comment: except when you get an AttributeError.

Comment: You don't always know what `attribute` is beforehand.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `MyClass.__attrs__`.  It just gives all the attributes of that class. Nothing more.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'X' has no attribute '__attrs__'