# Use `__dict__` or `vars()`?

Tags: python

Builtin function `vars()` looks more Pythonic to me, but I see `__dict__` used more frequently.

The Python documentation indicates that they are equivalent.

One blogger [claims that `__dict__` is faster than `vars()`](http://pythondoeswhat.blogspot.com/2012/01/dict-and-vars.html).

Which shall I use?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. In many cases, neither approach is the Right Way. In this broad a question, it seems that both work fine.

Comment: I generally go with `__dict__` just to avoid another layer of parentheses. Flat is better than nested and all.

Comment: I guess `__dict__` being slightly faster is no surprise. Accessing object attributes is faster than calling a function.

Comment: I don't know why but using `vars` seems cooler, and a little more neat. I can imagine this is more useful for beginners. It would be easier to explain, "Getting the vars of an object".

Comment: To me `__dict__` is more intuitive because I get back `dict` representation of an object.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd use [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars).

From: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DubiousPython#Premature_Optimization

> While a correctly applied optimization can indeed speed up code, optimizing code that is only seldom use [..] can make code harder to read. [..] Write correct code first, then make it fast (if necessary).

From: [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Readability counts.

Comment: why would `.__dict__` be over optimizing?

Comment: Since vars(obj) calls obj.__dict__(), you would be skipping this single call. But iljau recommends using vars() as it's more readable.

Comment: Using `.__dict__` to get a `dict` looks more readable to me than using `vars`.

Answer (score 86):

Generally, you should consider dunder/magic methods to be the implementation and invoking functions/methods as the API, so it would be preferable to use `vars()` over `__dict__`, in the same way that you would do `len(a_list)` and not `a_list.__len__()`, or `a_dict["key"]` rather than `a_dict.__getitem__('key')`

Comment: why is this prefereed?

Answer (score 22):

I agree `vars` should be preferred. My rationale is that, as python evolves, `vars` might be extended to do more than `__dict__` does (for example, work for [objects with slots](http://bugs.python.org/issue13290), possibly in 3.7).

Comment: The linked "objects with slots" idea was rejected though.