# Use str.format() to access object attributes

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a Python object with attributes `a`, `b`, `c`.

I still use old string formatting, so I'd normally print these manually:

```
 print 'My object has strings a=%s, b=%s, c=%s' % (obj.a, obj.b, obj.c)
```

Lately, my strings have been getting super long, and I'd much rather be able to simply pass the object into a string format function, something like:

```
 print 'My object has strings a=%a, b=%b, c=%c'.format(obj)
```

However, the syntax is incorrect.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the `.attribute_name` notation inside the format fields themselves:

```
print 'My object has strings a={0.a}, b={0.b}, c={0.c}'.format(obj)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...         self.c = c
...
>>> obj = Test(1, 2, 3)
>>> 'My object has strings a={0.a}, b={0.b}, c={0.c}'.format(obj)
'My object has strings a=1, b=2, c=3'
>>>
```

Note however that you do need to number the format fields when doing this.  Also, as you can see, the `str.format` function has its format fields denoted by curly braces `{...}`, not the `%` sign.

For more information, here is a reference on the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) in Python.

Comment: This looks better to me: `print 'My object has strings a={obj.a}, b={obj.b}, c={obj.c}'.format(obj=obj)`

Comment: Awesome guys, thanks.  Does the "0." (e.g. 0.a) denote the index of the item passed to format?

Comment: @AdamHughes - Exactly.  Python begins numbering at `0` just like C/C++.  `0` is the first (only) argument to `str.format`.

Comment: @RomanL - The OP disliked his current solution because it required you to type `obj` once per attribute.  Writing `obj` that many times is tedious and unnecessary IMO.  But, as you said, it is mainly a matter of preference. :)

Comment: That's right, but I still appreciate seeing the alternative approaches.  I was unaware of both cases!

Comment: @iCodez: `0` and `obj` are repeated the same number of times within the string. A realistic example with a shortened obj: `'a={o.a}, b={o.b}'.format(o=my_actual_object_name)`. To someone not familiar with this notation this is much more obvious than `0.a` IMO.

Comment: Also `'{a} {b}'.format(**vars(obj))` or `'{a} {b}'.format(**obj.__dict__)`

Comment: @iCodez can you this to access class methods as well? or just class attributes?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez - You can access methods, yes, but you will not be able to call them. Instead, you will get a string representation of the method like: `<bound method Class.method of <__main__.Class object at 0x0000000002CC27B8>>'`.

Answer (score 21):

I think it's preferable to use [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to access an object's attributes as a `dict` rather than usng `__dict__`.

So you could do this:

```
"My object has strings a={a}, b={b}, c={c}".format(**vars(obj))
```

For more background on why `vars()` is preferable to `__dict__`, see the answer to the question [Use **dict** or vars()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars).

Comment: if you define `__slots__` there is no `__dict__`, then `vars` wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 7):

As @igniteflow wrote in a buried comment:

```
'My object has strings a={a}, b={b}, c={c}'.format(**obj.__dict__)
```

With my limited python understanding: `.__dict__` is a dict with all the instances attributes and the `**` operator basically unpacks them and adds them as key=value args to the method

Comment: Nice! Using '**' is the key. Including .__dict__ in the example is unfortunate because it makes it look more complicated than it is. e.g. 'My object has strings a={a}, b={b}'.format(**{'a':'hi', 'b':'mom'})

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, building on @igniteflow and @Christian, you could use the `%` string format operator and write:

```
'My object has strings a=%(a)s, b=%(b)s, c=%(c)s' % obj.__dict__
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the suggested answers that rely on `vars(...)` don't work with immutable objects:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...   __slots__ = ()
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = 1
...
>>> vars(foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I think it's preferable to stick with something reliable and explicitly list what you need to be printed.

If you need to print a ton of attributes then storing those values as attributes might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

### With Formatted String Literals :

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...             return
... 
>>> a = A
>>> a.value = 123
>>> f' a.value is: {a.value}'
' a.value is: 123
```

You can directly access attributes from objects in your namespace.