# Print attribute of class based on attribute name

Tags: python

Is there a way to print out all the attributes of a python object along with their values

For example, for the following class and object

```
class man:
    def __init__(self):
      name = "jim"
      age = 2

him = man()
```

I want to print out all the attributes of the object "him" as well as their values. I want some kind of code that acts like the following

```
for variable_name of him:
    print variable_name," : ",him.variable_name
```

should print out

```
name : jim
age : 2
```

Is there any way to do that in python?

Comment: I think you meant `self.name = 'jim'` and `self.age = 2`.

Comment: Depends. Do you care about only what you have defined visibly in your class or do you want literally every property and method including those inherited from your own parent classes and built-in objects?

Comment: If you assign those vars to `self` then you can use `print(him.__dict__)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to properly define fields in your object:

```
class man(objet):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "jim"
        self.age = 2
```

Then you can use [`object.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__):

```
>>> him = man()
>>> himp.__dict__
{'name': 'jim', 'age': 2}
```

Comment: Alternatively, substitute `vars(him)` to `him.__dict__`. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars