# How to iterate on self attributes inside a class in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate on self attributes from self function in Python3, but I have not found any similar. I found how to do it outside the class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python).

My question is, is it possible?

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def method1(self):
        #Return sum of the values of the self attributes
        pass
```

Comment: you want to iterate through `attr1`, `attr2`?

Comment: Yep, themiurge and Gustavo comment correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a big fan of using `__dict__` for simple things. You should use `vars` to return a dict of your instance attributes

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
...         self.attr1 = attr1
...         self.attr2 = attr2
...     def method1(self):
...         return sum(vars(self).values())
... 
>>> Foo(2, 4).method1()
6
```

Comment: It is correct, that works fine. But, What is the differences? Performance, maybe?

Comment: In other response themiurge links this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars).

Answer (score 4):

You can access all attributes via the `__dict__` member:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def method1(self):
        return sum(self.__dict__.values())
```

You can also use [vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) (thanks to Azat Ibrakov and S.M.Styvane for pointing this out):

```
    def method1(self):
        return sum(vars(self).values())
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars) is a nice discussion on `__dict__` vs. `vars()`.

Comment: You can make it simply `sum(self.__dict__.values())`

Comment: or use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars): `sum(vars(self).values())`