# Turn Python object into JSON output

Tags: python, json

New to Python, trying to define a very simple class that will hold a few values, and then get it output into JSON notation.

```
import json

class Multiple:
    def __init__(self, basis):
            self.double = basis * 2
            self.triple = basis * 3
            self.quadruple = basis * 4


m = Multiple(100)
json.dumps(m)
```

I was hoping to see something like

```
{
  "double":"200",
  "triple":"300",
  "quadruple":"400"
}
```

but instead get an error: "TypeError: <**main**.Multiple object at 0x0149A3F0> is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can serialise the `__dict__` attribute of `m`:

```
In [214]: json.dumps(m.__dict__)
Out[214]: '{"quadruple": 400, "double": 200, "triple": 300}'
```

---

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834577/turn-python-object-into-json-output/45834618#comment78626512_45834618) also call [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
In [216]: json.dumps(vars(m))
Out[216]: '{"quadruple": 400, "double": 200, "triple": 300}'
```

What to use and why:
[Use `__dict__` or `vars()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars)

---

For more complicated classes, consider the use of [`jsonpickle`](http://jsonpickle.github.io).

> `jsonpickle` is a Python library for serialization and deserialization
>   of complex Python objects to and from JSON. The standard Python
>   libraries for encoding Python into JSON, such as the stdlib’s `json`,
>   `simplejson`, and `demjson`, can only handle Python primitives that have a
>   direct JSON equivalent (e.g. `dict`s, `list`s, `str`ings, `int`s, etc.).
>   **`jsonpickle` builds on top of these libraries and allows more complex
>   data structures to be serialized to JSON.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: beat me for a second , nice answer

Comment: @DanielSanchez Next time :)

Comment: it is better to use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, did not know about `vars` and had struggle sometimes with that. It is the useful tip of the day, thanks!!

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: Why is that better?

Comment: @Ryan: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300095/5997596)

Comment: So they handle superclass attributes identically... okay.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: I disagree with it in the case of `__dict__` just because `vars`’s overloading is icky.

Comment: @Ryan: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: “Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`.” That’s kind of what the name suggests it does, too. `__dict__` has one meaning and is pretty standard.