# How can I save the result from searchtweets into json files using python?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

I am recently working on twitter analysis and want to save the results from twitter search locally into .json files.

I am doing both historical search using "searchtweets" and streaming using "tweepy". The result I get are objects which are slightly different but I think both of the results are compatible with .json.

Here are my code(sample, I have a logged in to API already):

```
new_tweets = API.user_timeline(screen_name='huliangw20', count=20, 
tweet_mode='extended')

with open('test_tweets_v2.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(new_tweets)
```

It does not work. **In general, each query gives me a Resultset of many Tweet objects. And my goal is to save those objects into .json files using python.**

Would really appreciate if you could give me some advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the json standard library from python.

Reading a string as json:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

Transforming json as string:

```
>>> import json
>>print(json.dumps({"c": 0, "b": 0, "a": 0}, sort_keys=True))
{"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
```

With this function you can save on disk:

```
def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    try:
        filePathNameWExt = path + fileName
        with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)
    except Exception as e:
        if(not quiet):
            print "writeToJSONFile exception"
            print e
```

And finally generating a json on "hand":

```
>>> jsonToSave = {}
>>> jsonToSave['id'] = id
>>> metaJson = {}
>>> metaJson['version'] = VERSION
>>> jsonToSave['metadata'] = metaJson
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html
More info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Sorry I am quite confused. So the result I have is the variable "new_tweets", it is a set of "Tweet object" (each one of them contains all the information about a tweet) . How can I save them locally into one json file?

Comment: You can construct the json optimal for your application, per example, you can create a jsonToSave = {} and write just some parts of your "Tweet object" like: jsonToSave["Text"] = "bla bla", jsonToSave["Date"] = xx/yy/zzz so on.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I already know how to save a particular field into a file. The thing is I want to save the whole object for future use and there are like 100+ attributes. Just wondering if there is any quite way to save the whole thing?

Comment: Ohh now I got what u need, this format of json that I'm saying to you is a dict, you can cast objects to dict, look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834577/turn-python-object-into-json-output
That's help you?