# Test presence of class attribute in derived class, but not in parent class

Tags: python

I would like to check whether the `Child` class defined `classattr` (which might be also defined in its parent class). This is a MWE:

```py
class Base(object):
    classattr=1
class Child(Base):
    pass

print(hasattr(Child,'classattr'))
```

which prints `True`. The same happens using `inspect.getmebers`.

How can I find out in which class was the class attribute defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the `__dict__` has a key `classattr`

```
'classattr' in Child.__dict__
False
'classattr' in Base.__dict__
True
```

Comment: There exists an equivalent: `'classattr' in vars(Child)` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297203/use-dict-or-vars