# Getting all attributes to appear on python's `__dict__` method

Tags: python, class, attributes

Please consider the following python example:

```
In [3]: class test(object):
   ...:     attribute='3'
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.other='4'
   ...:         

In [4]: b=test()

In [5]: b.attribute
Out[5]: '3'

In [6]: b.__dict__
Out[6]: {'other': '4'}
```

Why is it that `__dict__` only shows the `"other"` attribute and not `"atribute"`?

And how do I get a dictionary with all the classe's attributes and values? That is, how do I get this?

```
{'other': '4', 'attribute': '3'}
```

And I mean by using `__dict__` or by some other simple means.

PS: related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class), but couldn't quite get a dict from there.

PS2: I'm not look for `test.__dict__` or `b.__class__.__dict__`, I'm looking for something that can be used as

```
In [3]: class test(object):
   ...:     attribute='3'
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.other='4'
   ...:     def _print_atr(self):
   ...:         # This should print exactly {'other': '4', 'attribute': '3'}
   ...:         print(self.__all_atr__)

In [4]: b=test()

In [5]: b.attribute
Out[5]: '3'

In [6]: b.__dict__
Out[6]: {'other': '4'}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by PS2?  Why does your hypothetical `__all_atr__` exclude `__init__` and `_print_atr` but it _does_ include `attribute`?

Comment: @mgilson yes, sorry if that wasn't clear, that's exactly what it would do. It would print out my excepted example: `{'other': '4', 'attribute': '3'}`.

Comment: But _why_?  What are the rules for excluding some things and not others?

Comment: @mgilson The idea is to consider both `b`'s attributes and `b`'s class attributes as attributes of `b`, while still maintaining python's default of "excluding" attributes that start with an underscore. But maybe this is a stupid way to do it to begin with. Do you believe I should delete the question?

Comment: No, I don't think you should necessarily delete the question.  If you just want to filter "dunder" attributes/methods, you could easily filter the dictionary from my answer:  `d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__')}`.  But I suppose it's also worth asking _why_ you want to do this.  What is the end goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`attribute` is not an instance attribute but a class attribute (can be seen in the *mappingproxy* `test.__dict__`).

You can get `attribute` in the instance `__dict__` if you update the value of `attribute` from the instance:

```
>>> b = test()
>>> b.__dict__
{'other': '4'}
>>> b.attribute
'3'
>>> b.attribute = 5
>>> b.__dict__
{'attribute': 5, 'other': '4'}
```

Or keep the original value with

```
>>> b.attribute  = b.__class__.attribute # may not be necessary
```

Or you could change the definition of the class and move `attribute` into one of the class methods and bind it to the instance via `self`.

Comment: +1 for this special mention: "You can get attribute in the instance __dict__ if you update the value of attribute from the instance"

Answer (score 3):

`b.__dict__` is only a mapping of attributes on `b`, not on `b`'s class (notice that `__init__` isn't there either).  The attributes on `b`'s class are on the class's `__dict__`.

```
>>> class test(object):
...   attribute = 1
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.other = 2
... 
>>> b = test()
>>> b.__dict__
{'other': 2}
>>> test.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'attribute': 1, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'test' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'test' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x1030f72a8>})
```

If you want both, you can do something like:

```
d = dict(vars(type(b)))
d.update(vars(b))
```

(note that some prefer `vars(b)` to `b.__dict__`)  Of course, this doesn't get subclasses ...

If you want subclasses, you'll need to walk the method resolution order...

```
d = {}
for cls in type(b).__mro__:
    d.update(vars(cls))
d.update(vars(b))
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'dictproxy' object has no attribute 'update'` when running update on `d`. Also, please see my edit, specifically "PS2".

Answer (score 1):

Try typing:

```
test.__dict__
```

And it shows a key with 'attribute'. This happens exactly because attribute is a class variable not an instance variable.

Comment: Thats the same as `b.__class__.__dict__`, but that doesn't really help as much. Please check my edit in about 5 minutes