# Get class variables without instantiating the class, but only from the class/type object?

Tags: python

Is it possible to find out which, if any, variables are set in a class's `__init__` method without instantiating the class and inspecting its `__dict__`?

For example, if you load a module called `mod` with some class called `Class`, you can get the properties and methods of the class without creating an instance of it, using `vars(mod.Class)`. If you create an instance of `Class`, you can also find out which variables are set upon instantiation, by looking at `mod.Class().__dict__` or using `vars(mod.Class())`.

I'm wondering if you can get the class variables without instantiation. I'm trying to inspect the variables of an arbitrary class/type. It doesn't appear that the `inspect` module provides such a function.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: Short of introspecting the code, no. This is because variables in `__init__` are not declared; they are simply *created* once the method runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that using the [type keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) in Python. There you have the example like this:

```
>>> class X:
...     a = 1
...
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `getattr`. You can use it to get the value of an attribute from a class.

```py
>>> class MyClass:
...     var = 1
...
>>> getattr(MyClass, "var")
1
```