# Python static method is not always callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, static-methods, callable

While parsing attributes using [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), my [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod) is not [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#callable).

```py
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 29 2016, 10:12:21)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
>>> class C(object):
...   @staticmethod
...   def foo():
...     for name, val in C.__dict__.items():
...       if name[:2] != '__':
...          print(name, callable(val), type(val))
...
>>> C.foo()
foo  False  <type 'staticmethod'>
```

- How is this possible?
- How to check if a static method is callable?

---

I provide below a more detailed example:

### Script `test.py`

```py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)

class C(object):

  @staticmethod
  def foo():
    return 42

  def bar(self):
    print('Is bar() callable?', callable(C.bar))
    print('Is foo() callable?', callable(C.foo))
    for attribute, value in C.__dict__.items():
      if attribute[:2] != '__':
        print(attribute, '\t', callable(value), '\t', type(value))

c = C()
c.bar()
```

### Result for python2

```py
> python2.7 test.py
Is bar() callable? True
Is foo() callable? True
bar      True    <type 'function'>
foo      False   <type 'staticmethod'>
```

### Same result for python3

```py
> python3.4 test.py
Is bar() callable? True
Is foo() callable? True
bar      True    <class 'function'>
foo      False   <class 'staticmethod'>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the descriptor protocol. The `C.foo` won't return a `staticmethod` but a normal function while the `'foo'` in `__dict__` is a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) (and `staticmethod` is a descriptor).

In short `C.foo` isn't the same as `C.__dict__['foo']` in this case - but rather `C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(C)` (see also the section in the documentation of the [Data model on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)):

```
>>> callable(C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(C))
True
>>> type(C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(C))
function

>>> callable(C.foo)
True
>>> type(C.foo)
function

>>> C.foo is C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(C)
True
```

---

In your case I would check for callables using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) (which knows about descriptors and how to access them) instead of what is stored as value in the class `__dict__`:

```
def bar(self):
    print('Is bar() callable?', callable(C.bar))
    print('Is foo() callable?', callable(C.foo))
    for attribute in C.__dict__.keys():
        if attribute[:2] != '__':
            value = getattr(C, attribute)
            print(attribute, '\t', callable(value), '\t', type(value))
```

Which prints (on python-3.x):

```
Is bar() callable? True
Is foo() callable? True
bar      True    <class 'function'>
foo      True    <class 'function'>
```

The types are different on python-2.x but the result of `callable` is the same:

```
Is bar() callable? True
Is foo() callable? True
bar      True    <type 'instancemethod'>
foo      True    <type 'function'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What should I change in my first snippet in order to known that `foo` is `callable`? Should I use `print(name, callable(val.__get__(C)))`? Or should I use something like `if type(name) == types.StaticmethodType`? Please advice a fix ;-) Cheers

Comment: Ah, I knew I forgot something. I updated the answer :)

Comment:  Yep `getattr(C, attribute)` does the job and I see that your `type(value)` returns now `<type 'instancemethod'>` instead of `<type 'staticmethod'>` in my code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't check if a `staticmethod` object is callable or not. This was discussed on the tracker in [Issue 20309 -- Not all method descriptors are callable](https://bugs.python.org/issue20309) and closed as "not a bug".

In short, there's been no rationale for implementing `__call__` for staticmethod objects. The built-in `callable` has no way to know that the `staticmethod` object is something that essentially "holds" a callable.

Though you could implement it (for `staticmethod`s and `classmethod`s), it would be a maintenance burden that, as previously mentioned, has no real motivating use-cases.

---

For your case, you can use `getattr(C, name)` to perform a look-up for the object named `name`; this is equivalent to performing `C.<name>`. `getattr`, after finding the staticmethod object, will invoke its `__get__` to get back the callable it's managing. You can then use `callable` on that.

A nice primer on descriptors can be found in the docs, take a look at [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent rational. I request the same as for MSeifert: What should I change in my first snippet in order to known that `foo` is `callable`? Should I use `print(name, callable(val.__get__(C)))`? Or should I use something like `if type(name) == types.StaticmethodType`? Please advice a fix ;-) Cheers

Comment: @olibre `callable(getattr(C, name))` is one option, it is always better than grabbing dunders (`__get__`)

Comment:  I have just successfully tested `getattr(C, attribute)`. You may write your comment in your answer. I see that `type(getattr(C, attribute))` returns `<type 'instancemethod'>` instead of `<type 'staticmethod'>` in my code. You may also explain it within your answer. Cheers

Comment: `getattr` is definitely the indisputably right option. The entire problem is that `obj.attr` does a bit more than just `obj.__dict__['attr']`, and just blindly trying to do `obj.__class__.__dict__['attr'].__get__(obj.__class__)` isn't right either because it ignores instance attributes, mro and non-descriptor attributes. `getattr` knows about all the complexities and does the right thing.

Comment: @olibre That's good. Both those objects (depending on Python version) are callable. Using `getattr` you've invoked the descriptor protocol (calling `staticmethod_obj.__get__`) and get back the callable it wraps. Take a look at the tutorial on [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods) for a nice overview.