# Method to write python module output to toml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, toml

I'm writing a scanner in python that will gather various information about a target such as open ports, version info and so on.
Also using a toml file that holds configuration settings for individual scans.

I need a method to store the scan results. So far I'm using a class that holds all target data. Is there a way to store the results in a file and have library functions parse and print them as requested?

In toml representation I'm thinking of something like

```
[target]
ip = xx.xx.xx.xx
  [target.os]
  os = 'win 10'
  Arch = 'x64'

  [target.ports]
  ports = ['1', '2']

    [target.ports.1]
    service = 'xxx'
    ver = '5.9'
```

Is there a way to dump scan results to toml file in this manner? Or is there another method that could do a better job?

Answer (score 10):

The [toml](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) library can do this for you. There are others like `json`, `pyyaml` etc that work in pretty much the same way. In your example, you would first need to store the information in a dictionary, in the following format:

```py
data = {
  "target": {
    "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "os": {
      "os": "win 10",
      "Arch": "x64"
    },
    "ports": {
      "ports": ["1", "2"],
      "1": {
        "service": "xxx",
        "ver": "5.9",
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Then, you can do:

```py
import toml

toml_string = toml.dumps(data)  # Output to a string

output_file_name = "output.toml"
with open(output_file_name, "w") as toml_file:
    toml.dump(data, toml_file)
```

Similarly, you can also **load** toml files into the dictionary format using:

```py
import toml

toml_dict = toml.loads(toml_string)  # Read from a string

input_file_name = "input.toml"
with open(input_file_name) as toml_file:
    toml_dict = toml.load(toml_file)
```

---

If instead of `toml` you want to use `yaml` or `json`, it is as simple as replacing `toml` with `yaml` or `json` in all the commands. They all use the same calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this stacktrace to achieve what you want to do:

**1.** You could probably extract the data of the class as a dictionary through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763434/7573706) method.

**2.** Write that to a file with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

**3.** From there load it into dictionary to toml converter with `toml.dump` with more info [here](https://pypi.org/project/toml/)