# Python: How to get attributes and their type from a dataclass?

Tags: python, oop, python-dataclasses

I'd like to read all attributes **and their types** from a (data)class, as shown in this desired (pseudo)code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    name: str = 'Earth'
    is_planet: bool = True
    radius: int = 6371


if __name__ == '__main__':
    attrs = get_attributes(HelloWorld)
    for attr in attrs:
        print(attr.name, attr.type)  # name, str
```

I checked several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class), but couldn't find what I need yet.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For classes in general, you can access the `__annotations__`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    bar: int
...    baz: str
...
>>> Foo.__annotations__
{'bar': <class 'int'>, 'baz': <class 'str'>}
```

This returns a `dict` mapping attribute name to annotation.

However, dataclasses have use `dataclass.field` objects to encapsulate a lot of this information. You can use `dataclasses.fields` on an instance or on the class:

```
>>> import dataclasses
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
... class Foo:
...     bar: int
...     baz: str
...
>>> dataclasses.fields(Foo)
(Field(name='bar',type=<class 'int'>,default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD), Field(name='baz',type=<class 'str'>,default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD))
```

NOTE:

[Starting in Python 3.7, the evaluation of annotations can be postponed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7):

```
>>> from __future__ import annotations
>>> class Foo:
...     bar: int
...     baz: str
...
>>> Foo.__annotations__
{'bar': 'int', 'baz': 'str'}
```

note, the annotation is kept as a *string*, this also affects `dataclasses` as well:

```
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
... class Foo:
...     bar: int
...     baz: str
...
>>> dataclasses.fields(Foo)
(Field(name='bar',type='int',default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD), Field(name='baz',type='str',default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f806369bc10>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD))
```

So, just be aware, since this will become the standard behavior, code you write should probably use the `__future__` import and work under that assumption, because in Python 3.10, this will become the standard behavior.

The motivation behind this behavior is that the following currently raises an error:

```
>>> class Node:
...    def foo(self) -> Node:
...        return Node()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in Node
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

But with the new behavior:

```
>>> from __future__ import annotations
>>> class Node:
...     def foo(self) -> Node:
...         return Node()
...
>>>
```

One way to handle this is to use the `typing.get_type_hints`, which I believe just basically `eval`'s the type hints:

```
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Node.foo)
{'return': <class '__main__.Node'>}
>>> class Foo:
...    bar: int
...    baz: str
...
>>> Foo.__annotations__
{'bar': 'int', 'baz': 'str'}
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Foo)
{'bar': <class 'int'>, 'baz': <class 'str'>}
```

Not sure how reliable this function is, but basically, it handles getting the appropriate `globals` and `locals` of *where the class was defined*. So, consider:

```
(py38) juanarrivillaga@Juan-Arrivillaga-MacBook-Pro ~ % cat test.py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing

class Node:
    next: Node

(py38) juanarrivillaga@Juan-Arrivillaga-MacBook-Pro ~ % python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.Node
<class 'test.Node'>
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(test.Node)
{'next': <class 'test.Node'>}
```

Naively, you might try something like:

```
>>> test.Node.__annotations__
{'next': 'Node'}
>>> eval(test.Node.__annotations__['next'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

You could hack together something like:

```
>>> eval(test.Node.__annotations__['next'], vars(test))
<class 'test.Node'>
```

But it can get tricky

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
```

`Point.__annotations__` returns `{'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>}`.