# How to get attributes of a class without Pydantic BaseModel?

Tags: python, pydantic, class-attributes

This solution seemed like it would help solve my problem: [Getting attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class)

However, when I follow the steps linked above, my project only returns `Config` and `fields`. This is likely because these classes inherit from Pydantic's `BaseModel`.

What I'm looking for is for a class, say:

```
class GameStatistics(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    status: str
    scheduled: datetime
```

I should return `id`, `status`, and `scheduled`.

My attempt:

```
for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(module, lambda member: inspect.isclass(member) and member.__module__== module.__name__):

    for _name, attrbs in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda member: not(inspect.isroutine(member))):
        if not _name.startswith('_'):
            print(_name, attrbs)
```

Comment: *I follow the steps linked above* then please provide piece of code which *only return Config and fields*

Comment: How about `GameStatistics.__fields__`

Comment: If you need this info for objects of this class, all you need is `object.dict()`. But if you want something for the class itself, that's more complicated.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution that doesn't use Pydantic/BaseModel's "magic" methods and properties? Purely Python class methods and properties?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for field in GameStatistics.__fields__:
    print(field)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension would be a cleaner way to do this if you want to do something with the value.

```
[field for field in GameStatistics.__fields__.keys()]
```

or just

```
list(GameStatistics.__fields__.keys())
```