# Python inherited type variables

Tags: python, inheritance, types

I suppose i'm misunderstand how type inheritance work in python.

While i'm defining variable inside Parent class, any Child class inherited in parent
referencing same variable from parent.

```py
class Parent(object):
    store = dict()

class ChildA(Parent):
   pass

class ChildB(Parent):
   pass

ChildA.store['key1'] = 'val' 
ChildB.store['key2'] = 'val'

print ChildB.store['key1'] == ChildA.store['key2']
```

What i'm trying to achieve is `store` dictionary instance to be created in every `Child` class inherited from `Parent`. So referencing `ChildB.store['key1']` would raise `KeyError`

I have tried to use `__new__` to create dictionary instance while type is creating:

```py
class NewParent(object):  
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        rv = super(NewParent,cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        rv.store = dict()
        return rv
```

But it's seems like `__new__` running only before instantiating `Child` class, so referencing variable via type (e.g. `Child.store` is raising `AttributeError`)

So is there any way to achieve behavior i want?

Comment: You want a metaclass, which is the "class of a class". For instance, see http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my instance variable not in \_\_dict\_\_?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805/why-is-my-instance-variable-not-in-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a metaclass, which lets you initialize a class definition sort of like how a constructor lets you initalize an instance. For more details, see http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example/.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

class ParentMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        dct['store'] = dict()
        return super(ParentMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = ParentMeta

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
   pass

ChildA.store['key1'] = 'val'
ChildB.store['key2'] = 'val'

print ChildB.store['key1'] == ChildA.store['key2']
```

will result in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print ChildB.store['key1'] == ChildA.store['key2']
KeyError: 'key1'
```